# for loop for searching for a value inside of a firestore array

Tags: swift

Im basically trying to do a for loop I have an array in firestore and im trying to have the for loop check for a specific ID inside that array and and then return true if the string was found or false if it wasn't Im not too sure if thats a smart idea or the best way to implement it.

the main goal is to see if the string userId which is basically the current Users id to see if its in the array

```
     func checkArray(path : String)-> Bool{
    if(MUser.currentUser() != nil){
        FirebaseReferece(.Verses).document(path).collection(rUSERHASLIKEDARRAY).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if(error != nil){
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                //perform loop to search for specific user ID

                let userId  = MUser.currentAuthID() //so now we have to match this string to a string in an array

                let arrayData = snapshot?.documents

                if(arrayData != nil){

                    for userString in arrayData! {




                    }
                }else {

                    print("user has not liked")
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply search for userID in arrayData:

```
for userString in arrayData! {
            if (userString.contains(userID))
 // Than you do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: but userId is a string and when you call user string.contains it wants a querySnapshot

Comment: I didn't get what you want to say, as I see - userString is String and userId is String too, so you can use "contains method"

Comment: I  figured it out I rewrote the function it was asking for a query snapshot because of the way I accessed firestore thank you for the help